# What mistake am I making if even root cannot delete a lock file created using O_CREAT | O_EXCEL?

Tags: c++, unix, solaris

We have created a lock file to avoid a race condition. The lockfile is created in `/tmp` directory, which has the sticky bit set. We are not passing the mode of the file as the optional 
third argument during the file creation. And the file is created using `fopen` function and

```
int fd = fopen(filename, O_CREAT | O_EXCEL);
```

We are deleting this lockfile once its use is over. But sometimes the file is not deleted
and it remains in the `/tmp` folder, blocking the other process and the application remains just active without proceeding further.  The lock file is being deleted by sending command to system 
and the command used is `/usr/bin -rf`. What was surprising that neither the file owner nor the root user was able to delete the file after that.

> Doing an operation `ll lockfile` in `/tmp` folder gave an O/P in permission
>            section "---x------", which I could not decipher. Changing the permission of
>            the lockfile with `chmod 777 filename` through `root` user id does not work.
>            And the system has to be rebooted to get the lockfile removed from the `/tmp` dir.

Comment: Was the file closed before deletion?  As long as there are lingering open connections, the file will not be deleted until the last one is closed.  But there would be no conventional directory entry after deletion.

Comment: The file was not closed before deletion , but it works in my case may be because we are using /usr/bin -rf to remove the file . This scenario is a very rare case which we get once in a month and not very often or everytime we create the lockfile

Comment: If the command you execute is truly `/usr/bin -rf` and not (as would more normally be the case) `/usr/bin/rm -rf`, then the problem is that you are executing a directory, not a command, and it doesn't work.  Besides, your program that uses `open()` should simply use `remove()` (Standard C) or `unlink()` (POSIX; pre-dates `remove()` by almost two decades).  The `----x-----` string means 'execute permission for owner; no permission for anyone else'.  If your `/tmp` file system is NFS mounted (unlikely, but not impossible), then root has few privileges on that file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you're creating the file like this:

```
int fd = fopen(filename, O_CREAT | O_EXCEL);
```

That does not match the signature of fopen:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

So I presume you might actually be using open:

```
int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_EXCL);
```

Which is an error because the third argument to open(2) is "mode" and it is mandatory when O_CREAT is used.

Since you are not passing the mode argument, you are invoking undefined behavior, and the mode is probably getting set to some undesired value.  Try passing 0666 as the third argument to open(2) and see if that helps.

Comment: Wow good point. I bet what is happening to him is the `open` system call is pulling the third argument off the stack. Except that in the call he never put it *on* the stack. So it is getting some garbage.

Comment: And I bet some of that garbage is high bit flags with special meaning. He might want to look at lsattr to see if the file was created as immutable or something similar. That might be why it cannot be deleted.

Comment: Yes.  This is something that static analysis tools should be able to catch, but at least GCC with typical options does not.  A fairly common error, and one I've made myself!

Comment: @ZanLynx  May be thats the case but Why this is a rare scenario as we use the Application daily and perform the operation hundred of times ? This occurs almost once in a month

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior.  It's sheer luck that the program does not simply crash every time.  Or maybe unlucky--if it had, you would have found this bug early!

Comment: @Ritesh: It would just depend on what was on the stack or in the CPU registers (depends on the system's function call protocol) when the call was made. The problem may happen only when some previous call has used an unusual value.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks for all your input , i did guess that this must have been the problem . But this happening very rarely made me suspicious . Will go through code thoroughly tomorrow and mark it as the answer most probably as i believe this will solve my issue .

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile to fix the problem and delete the file -- as root run this:

```
chmod 755 /tmp/lockfile
rm /tmp/lockfile
```

Comment: 'did not work' does not help us help you.  please show the exact output of ls -l /tmp/lockfile,  please show any error you got trying to delete /tmp/lockfile

Comment: This was the O/P of ls operation root@typhoon> ls -al |grep lck 
        `---x------ 1 user1 nms 0 Feb 3 15:49 lockfile`

Comment: chown root:root lck  then chmod and rm.

Comment: we have tried all these the chmod doesnt work . If that would have been possible, i guess it would have allowed us to remove the lockfile in the first place. Regards

Comment: In all honesty - you are not giving me everything.  Either the file name is somehow corrupted, like an extra unprintable character is on the file name, or you did whatever I asked a long time ago. Not an hour ago. And you assume it does not work now, I guess.  Does ls lck work?  If it does not find the problem then your file name is screwed up.  I ask that because you used ls | grep to list the file. ls does not need grep to find a single file, like ls myfilename.  If this is the case: ls | grep lck | od -c  will show the filename plus junk characters.

Comment: Hi Jim the O/P as you asked for is :- 
root@cool> ls | grep *.lck | od -c
0000000   i   m   p   o   r   t   e   r   .   l   c   k  \n
0000015
and root@cool> ll importer.lck
---x--l---   1 root     nms            0 Feb 21 10:40 importer.lck
I dont understand What is this `l stands for here in  ---x--l--- `

Comment: The file appears to have a blocking mandatory lock on it, the OS will not let you do anything to the file.  If this is true, you cannot delete it until the system reboots.  There may also be a running process on it with that lock.  The fuser command (or lsof if you have it) can assist you.

Comment: YA true , chmod did not work but somehow chown did work and i was finally able to delete it . Thanks for all your help . Btw why is this mandatory lock created ? Is it because i did not pass mode while creating file using o_creat ?